# Is there a mathematical difference between nonsmooth and nondifferentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Apologies for stupid question. It is just that I am not able to differentiate between nonsmooth and nondifferentiable function.

> Is there any difference between nonsmooth and nondifferentiable function, mathematically speaking?

Comment: Define "smooth" and "differentiable", and compare.

Comment: Typically, a function is said to be smooth if it has continuous derivatives of all orders, and differentiable only if it has a single derivative.  So the difference is...?  That being said, as vonbrand suggests, the additional context of proper definitions of "smooth" and "differentiable" would greatly improve your question.

Comment: @vonbrand Thank You.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Thank You.

Comment: No questions are stupid, or if they are, the only way to learn is to ask them, so you still should. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are rather similar, but still different!

Here are the definitions of differentiable and smooth from wikipedia:

A differentiable function of one real variable is a function whose derivative exists at each point in its domain.

A smooth function is a function that has derivatives of all orders everywhere in its domain.

An important difference between the definitions is a differentiable function may only have a finite number of derivatives, whereas smooth functions have derivatives of all orders. This leads to the following logic:

All smooth functions are differentiable. Therefore, all non-differentiable are non-smooth. However, there are some differentiable functions that are not smooth (see linked question). Therefore, there are some functions that are not smooth, but are differentiable.

[Does there exist a continuous and differentiable function which isn't smooth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153393/does-there-exist-a-continuous-and-differentiable-function-which-isnt-smooth)

For further explanation, look at the Differentiability Classes section on wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function

Comment: Thank You. This is so useful to me, especially, this "Does there exist a continuous and differentiable function which isn't smooth? "

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They're totally different, just look up the definitions with Google. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Examples) about smoothness shows an explicit example:

Take $g(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \mathrm{sin}(\frac{1}{x}) \quad \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 \quad \text{if } x = 0\end{cases}$. This function is differentiable but not of class $C^1$ and, therefore, nonsmooth.

Comment: Thank You......